# Scheme for using git in nested, dependent projects

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I have two folders namely "SubProject1" and "SubProject2" inside a "MainProject" folder. I would like to use git to control the versions of MainProject, SubProject1, and SubProject2. Independent teams will be responsible for developing these 3 projects. The three projects are inter connected and one project will use files from other projects. How can I use git to independently control the work flow of the three projects, at the same time allowing to keep the dependencies between the projects?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using Git Submodules.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

You would be able to have your sub-projects as submodules of your main project.  In the main project, you end up keeping track of what state the submodules are supposed to be in.  So then you would be able to develop in the exact manner that you are looking for.